# Неправильно рисуется куб

Tags: c, opengl

Захотел я сделать затекстуреный куб на си и openGL и вот...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include<../../stb_image.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC*, HGLRC*);
void DisableOpenGL(HWND, HDC, HGLRC);


unsigned int texture;

void LoadTexture(char *filename, int *textureID){
    int width, height, cnt;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(filename, &width, &height, &cnt, 0);

    glGenTextures(1, textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *textureID);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height,
                                    0, cnt == 4 ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    stbi_image_free(data);
}


void Init(){
    LoadTexture("wood.jpg", &texture);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-0.1, 0.1, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2,1000);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}


float vertex[] = {-1,-1,0, 1,-1,0, 1,1,0, -1,1,0
                -1,-1,2, 1,-1,2, 1,1,2, -1,1,2};

float texCoord[] = {0,1, 1,1, 0,1, 1,1,
                    0,0, 1,0, 0,0, 1,0};
GLuint texInd[] = {0,1,5, 5,4,0, 1,2,6, 6,5,1, 2,3,7, 7,6,2, 3,0,4, 4,7,3};
int cnt = sizeof(texInd) / sizeof(GLuint);

float texCoord2[] = {0,1, 1,1, 1,0, 0,0,
                    0,1, 1,1, 1,0, 0,0};
GLuint texInd2[] = {0,1,2, 2,3,0, 4,5,6, 6,7,4};
int cnt2 = sizeof(texInd2) / sizeof(GLuint);


void Draw(){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Init();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(-70, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(33, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslatef(2,3,-2);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertex);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoord);
        glPushMatrix();
            glScalef(1,1,0.6);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, cnt, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, texInd);
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoord2);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, cnt2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, texInd2);
        glPopMatrix();
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glPopMatrix();
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;
    float theta = 0.0f;

    /* register window class */
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);;


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    /* create main window */
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
                          "GLSample",
                          "OpenGL Sample",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          500,
                          500,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* enable OpenGL for the window */
    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    /* program main loop */
    while (!bQuit)
    {
        /* check for messages */
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            /* handle or dispatch messages */
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* OpenGL animation code goes here */

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            Draw();

            SwapBuffers(hDC);

            theta += 1.0f;
            Sleep (1);
        }
    }

    /* shutdown OpenGL */
    DisableOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);

    /* destroy the window explicitly */
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            return 0;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    /* get the device context (DC) */
    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    /* set the pixel format for the DC */
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
                  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    /* create and enable the render context (RC) */
    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}

void DisableOpenGL (HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}
```

PS:Редактор кода CodeBlocks

Comment: ¿Куб из 4 треугольников? Свежо...

Comment: Верно я читаю, что ваш куб строится только из 8+4 треугольников? И почему в 2 приема?

Comment: Я бы хотел помочь но тут и текстуры и анимация и Windows. Если бы только пример был проще, не зависел от ресурсов и был написан переносимым образом.